# iOS App Update - Remove old core data records, user defaults, etc

Tags: ios

We're building a new version of an iOS application and are making fundamental changes to how the application works, stores data, etc. Is there a way to remove old core data records, any stored defaults, etc. when the user upgrades to the new version, such that it is essentially starting from a blank slate as if freshly installed?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just release it as a new app? If it's going to remove all the old data and all the old preferences, it is, to all intents and purposes, a new app anyway.

Having said that, there are two answers to this.

For Core Data, the easiest way is probably just to create a new database (and delete the old one). That way you won't have any migration problems either.

For the user defaults, you can get all the keys using the `dictionaryRepresentation` method of `NSUserDefaults`. You can remove the uninteresting ones from there.

Answer (score 0):

In your applicationDelegate, you have:

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{}
```

Consider the following:

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Check newly created userdefault if we need to clear the environment.
    if ([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"didClearEnvironment"]isEqualToString:@"Completed"])
    {
        // Environment already cleared.

    } 
    else
    {
        // Do code to clear your application.
        [Self clearApplicationenvironment];

        //Create a stored default to tell the application that this is only supposed to happen once.
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setValue:@"Completed" forKey@"didClearEnvironment"];
    }


    // the rest of your code     
}
```

Disclaimer: This was written in notepad, chances that written code wont work at all.

Hope it gave you some ideas :)

Comment: It is not a good idea to do that in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions since such operations can be heavy - and application has only few seconds to become active - otherwise it will be killed by iOS. But idea with a clear flag - is proper solution.